# Can't control width of table elements added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I used JavaScript for loops to create a 16x16 grid by appending elements to a table. This works fine, except I can't control the width of the boxes via css - they always come out very narrow. I can style other aspects, including height, but altering the width property has no effect. I've tried messing with the display, margin, and padding properties, with various outcomes, but never anything useful.

Here's my code.
 
**Javascript**

```
for (var r=0; r<16; r++) {
    $('table').append("<tr></tr>");
};
for (var c=1; c<16; c++) {
    $('tr').append("<td class='grid'></td>");
};
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
height: 10px; width: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: You're not doing what you expect. You're adding a single cell to every row. Try using `$('tr').map(function(i,nonJQelement){ /* Inserting cell loop */});`

Comment: @Pluto: _“You're adding a single cell to every row”_ – yes, but that is done 16 times in a loop.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xf63zgj6/ (at least in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out CBroe. Going off of that, I discovered that the problem was with the "container" div I wrapped the table in, and the CSS that I had applied to that (I had applied height and width properties. Removing those solved the problem).

Comment: Huh, I seemed to miss something. The one mistake there is with your code that you might miss is that you're only adding 15 cells per row, not 16. The second loop starts at 1 instead of 0.